Error message: Download Playwright on my Windows Laptop
Im trying to download playwright on visual studio on my windows computer but it came up with this error message even though I have downloaded node.js. I tried to download it using npm by using the command npm init playwright@latest but failed. It does tell me the questions like Do you want to use Javascript or Typescript" but after I answer the questions it comes up with this error message.
It came up with the same error message for pnpm
npm error code 1
npm error path G:\My Drive\Learning_Playwright
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-playwright
npm notice
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.8.1 -> 10.8.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2       
npm notice
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Luke McDonald\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-13T03_38_19_730Z-debug-0.log"`

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
I did have a go at looking at downloading yarn and pnpm but then it came up with this error message
"yarn : The term 'yarn' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or     
operable program. Check the spelling of the     
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn create playwright
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (  
   yarn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundEx  
   ception`

